# Unable able to see Pods CPU and Memory Utilization and graphs are missing Kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

K8s VERSION = v1.18.6

I have deployed the Kubernetes dashboard using the following command and added a privileged user with which I logged into the dashboard.

but not able to  see Pods CPU and Memory Utilization graphs are missing  Kubernetes dashboard[image]

Comment: Can you give more details about the application & Kubernetes setup, like what application is running in the pods and which kubernetes service are you using, minikube, EKS, AKS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kubernetes Metrics Server is an aggregator of resource usage data in your cluster,
To deploy the Metrics Server

Deploy the Metrics Server with the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.6/components.yaml
```

Verify that the metrics-server deployment is running the desired number of pods with the following command.

```
kubectl get deployment metrics-server -n kube-system
```

Output

```
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
metrics-server   1/1     1            1           6m
```

Also you can validate by below command:

```
kubectl top nodes
```

to see node cpu utilisation if it works, it should then come up in Dashboard as well.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening to me. Metrics server is installed, `kubectl top nodes` does what I expect, but still no graphs in the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Resource usage metrics are only available for K8s clusters once [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) has been installed.